# PHP APC causing Apache to seg fault

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, apc

First, versions:

Apache 2.2.22
PHP 5.3.10
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (everything updated)
APC 3.1.7 (installed via APT and not PEAR)

The problem I'm experiencing is that when issuing a graceful restart (`sudo service apache2 graceful`), PHP has a fatal error which causes Apache to seg fault. This is what I see in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Tue Apr 30 11:05:33 2013] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
PHP Fatal error:  PHP Startup: apc_mmap: mmap failed: in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Apr 30 11:05:34 2013] [notice] seg fault or similar nasty error detected in the parent process
```

`/etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini` only contains the following:

```
extension=apc.so
apc.shm_size=256M
```

[Linode](http://www.linode.com/) is my host. I have the 1GB version with a 256MB swap partition, so 256M should be a reasonable value for `apc.shm_size` (prior to the recent [Linode memory upgrade](http://blog.linode.com/2013/04/09/linode-nextgen-ram-upgrade/), I only had 512MB of memory, and `apc.shm_size` was set to 128M).

Here is some general cache information as shown in `apc.php`:

```
APC Version 3.1.7
PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6
APC Host    [removed]
Server Software Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Shared Memory   1 Segment(s) with 256.0 MBytes
(mmap memory, pthread mutex Locks locking)
Start Time  2013/04/30 11:09:44
Uptime  21 minutes
File Upload Support 1
```

Here are my runtime settings as shown in `apc.php`:

```
apc.cache_by_default    1
apc.canonicalize    1
apc.coredump_unmap  0
apc.enable_cli  0
apc.enabled 1
apc.file_md5    0
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters 
apc.gc_ttl  3600
apc.include_once_override   0
apc.lazy_classes    0
apc.lazy_functions  0
apc.max_file_size   1M
apc.mmap_file_mask  
apc.num_files_hint  1000
apc.preload_path    
apc.report_autofilter   0
apc.rfc1867 0
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
apc.serializer  default
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    256M
apc.slam_defense    1
apc.stat    1
apc.stat_ctime  0
apc.ttl 0
apc.use_request_time    1
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl    0
apc.write_lock  1
```

I've done a ton of searching around, but I just can't figure out what's causing this. Is this perhaps a PHP or APC or Apache bug? Is there some configuration value I need to add/change?

Thanks for any help!

[edit]
I just tried updating APC (removed it in apt and installed through PECL), but that didn't fix the problem. I still see seg faults with APC 3.1.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around, I noticed a troublesome line in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
kernel: apache2[11303]: segfault at ffffffff ip b7647bd8 sp bfe854b0 error 7 in libpthread-2.15.so[b763f000+17000]
```

After a little Googling, I came across https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1159748, a confirmed bug in the Ubuntu Apache distribution. I'm glad I'm not crazy! If anyone else encounters this, be sure to follow the progress on this bug.

Answer (score 2):

It might have to do with the shared memory allowed for a segment in the OS which can be significantly lower then 256MB.

Check the output of `sudo sysctl kernel.shmmax`. On my debian machine it's 33554432 (32MB).

As a possible solution. Try to increase `apc.shm_segments` to 256 / 32 = 8 in your APC config. You could also change the allowed shared memory for a segment system wide to 256MB.

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.shmmax 268435456
```

Comment: I actually came across this explanation, but then I stumbled on http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php, which states, "When APC is compiled with mmap support (Memory Mapping), it will use only one memory segment, unlike when APC is built with SHM (SysV Shared Memory) support that uses multiple memory segments. MMAP does not have a maximum limit like SHM does in /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax." I'm using mmap, so I don't think this is the issue. I'll try anyway just to be sure....

Comment: Yeah, I changed `apc.shm_segments` to 8, but apc.php still says "1 Segment(s) with 256.0 MBytes (mmap memory, pthread mutex Locks locking)", which confirms what the PHP docs say.